# Spacy phrasematcher does not get matcher name

Tags: spacy

I am new to phraseMatcher and want to extract some keyword from my emails.
Everything is working well except that I can't get a name of added matcher.

This is my code below:

```
def main():
    patterns_months = 'phraseMatcher/months.txt'
    text_loc = 'phraseMatcher/text.txt'
    nlp = spacy.blank('en')
    nlp.vocab.lex_attr_getters ={}
    phrases_months = read_gazetter(patterns_months)
    txts = read_text(text_loc, n=n)

    months = [nlp(text) for text in phrases_months]

    matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
    matcher.add('MONTHS', None, *months)
    print(nlp.vocab.strings['MONTHS'])

    for txt in txts:
        doc = nlp(txt)
        matches = matcher(doc)

        for match_id ,start, end in matches:
            span = doc[start: end]
            label = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
            print(label, span.text, start, end)
```

The result:

```
12298211501233906429          <--- this is from print(nlp.vocab.strings['MONTHS'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workspace/phraseMatcher/venv/phraseMatcher.py", line 71, in <module>
    plac.call(main)
  File "D:\workspace\phraseMatcher\venv\lib\site-packages\plac_core.py", line 328, in call
    cmd, result = parser.consume(arglist)
  File "D:\workspace\phraseMatcher\venv\lib\site-packages\plac_core.py", line 207, in consume
    return cmd, self.func(*(args + varargs + extraopts), **kwargs)
  File "D:/workspace/phraseMatcher/venv/phraseMatcher.py", line 47, in main
    label = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
  File "strings.pyx", line 117, in spacy.strings.StringStore.__getitem__
KeyError: "[E018] Can't retrieve string for hash '18446744072093410045'."
```

- spaCy version:** 2.0.12
- Platform:** Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
- Python version:** 3.7.0

I can't find what I did wrong. It is simple and I read these already:
[Using PhraseMatcher in SpaCy to find multiple match types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638877/using-phrasematcher-in-spacy-to-find-multiple-match-types)

Help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help a lot if you had a snippet of the actual code to look over. I.e. a few examples of where your months entity might exist.

Comment: This actually worked for me  label = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]