# check similarity or synonyms between word in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I want to find synonyms of words.

If word is `tall building` then i want to find all synonyms of this word like `"long apartment ,large building"`etc

I used Spacy.

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

LOOP
nlp('tall building').similarity(nlp(mytokens[i]))
```

I can't use this because it takes a lot of time

[neither I can use PhraseMatcher for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638877/using-phrasematcher-in-spacy-to-find-multiple-match-types)

Please help me

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

you could try using beautiful soup to parse data from an online thesaurus    or use a python module such as [py-thesaurus]:https://pypi.org/project/py-thesaurus/

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
 from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
 from urllib.error import HTTPError




def find_synonym(string):
    """ Function to find synonyms for a string"""


    try:

        # Remove whitespace before and after word and use underscore between words
        stripped_string = string.strip()
        fixed_string = stripped_string.replace(" ", "_")
        print(f"{fixed_string}:")

        # Set the url using the amended string
        my_url = f'https://thesaurus.plus/thesaurus/{fixed_string}'
        # Open and read the HTMLz
        uClient = uReq(my_url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()

        # Parse the html into text
        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
        word_boxes = page_soup.find("ul", {"class": "list paper"})
        results = word_boxes.find_all("div", "list_item")

        # Iterate over results and print
        for result in results:
            print(result.text)

    except HTTPError:
        if "_" in fixed_string:
            print("Phrase not found! Please try a different phrase.")

        else:
            print("Word not found! Please try a different word.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_synonym("hello ")
```

Comment: Yes just read that py- thesaurus will not be continued, in the meantime the above script should work.

Answer (score 0):

So it's a little hard to tell from your example, but it looks like you're creating a new spaCy doc in every iteration of your loop, which will be slow. You should do something like this instead:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

query = nlp('tall building')
for token in mytokens:
    query.similarity(nlp(token))
```

This way spaCy only has to create the query doc once.

If you want to make repeated queries, you should put the vector for each doc in [annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) or similar to get the most similar doc quickly.

Also, I generally wouldn't call this finding "synonyms" since every example you gave is multiple words. You're really looking for similar phrases. "Synonyms" would usually imply single words, like you'd find in a thesaurus, but that won't help you here.